# Testing the difference between multiple paired proportions with different sample sizes

Tags: multiple-comparisons, proportion, paired-data

Is there a hypothesis test similar to the paired t-test for testing if the difference between a number of paired proportion estimates is significantly different from zero? The data consists of 2 lists of paired proportion estimates and each proportion estimate may be based on a different sample size.

Essentially, I calculated proportions for two groups from data collected on the same day; these data span the entire year. For example:

```
              A           B
Day 1:      88/288,      5/50
Day 2:      60/275,      9/288
Day 3:       6/30,      65/280
Day 4:       7/288,    250/288
...
Day 365:   288/288,      0/288
```

Thus far, I've only found tests designed for a single pair of proportions.

Comment: Is your alternative hypothesis that there's a consistent effect in the pair-comparisons across days (e.g. B's proportion tends to be on one side of A's,), or are you looking for an alternative of anything-but-equality (e.g. B's population proportion could be higher than A sometimes and lower sometimes but isn't always equal to A's)?